# flex 4: resize SWFLoader element to fit inside a VGroup element

Tags: flex4, resize, swfloader

I'm trying to resize a flash game inside a VGroup, no matter what configuration i try to set, some of my flash games are clipped out. i see only 80% of the actual flash screen.

this is my code:

```
<s:VGroup id="gameVGroup" clipAndEnableScrolling="true" height="480" maxHeight="480" width="540" maxWidth="540">
        <mx:SWFLoader id="swfGameLoader" loadForCompatibility="true" scaleContent="true" maintainAspectRatio="true" width="100%" height="100%" maxWidth="540" maxHeight="480" />
    </s:VGroup>
```

any ideas?

## update

i still want to maintain aspect ratio.
so if the game is wider or taller then my application window, i want it to be resized properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
maintainAspectRatio="false"
```

Comment: i would prefer to maintain aspect ratio.

Comment: then add Enter_Frame event handler and check the sizes of container and content of container manually.

Comment: don't forget to share your solution, btw instead of enterFrame event you could call listen to RESIZE and creationComplete events, it will optimize memory usage.